# ACPI BIOS Error at start : AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT

Tags: boot, acpi, buffer

Since few hours, my HP Elitebook won't start and block at BIOS error. I run with Linux Mint 20.

After read some threads, I upgrade the BIOS, but the bug is always here.

Here is the return display :

```
[0.444122] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, FIELD [CAP1] at bit offset/length 64/32 exceeds size of target buffer (64bits) 20190816/dsopcode-198)

[0.444171] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB._OSC due to previous error (AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu  1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Some ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution : doing a [manual fsck](https://linuxhandbook.com/fsck-command/) to repair file system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).